# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1

Tags: android, android-layout

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1
android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:137)
at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:85)
at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:81)
```

above is the error and below is the layout for the error. Everything i read says that the xml needs to have one parent layout, which mine does. what else could be wrong?

This is the layout for my main activity that gets launched when app launches

this is my min/target

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#292929"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/header_height" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/apply"
        android:id="@+id/apply"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:background="#3fb0ff"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/wallpaper"
        android:id="@+id/wallpapers"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:background="#3994d8"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/request_icons"
        android:id="@+id/requesticons"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:background="#3376b4"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/view_icons"
        android:id="@+id/viewicons"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:background="#2c5f95"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rate"
            android:maxHeight="100dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/main_button_bottom_rate"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/gplus"
            android:maxHeight="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/main_button_bottom_gplus"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/morework"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:maxHeight="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/main_button_bottom_morework"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/contact"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxHeight="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/main_button_bottom_contact"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Which API you are using?

Comment: you xml is too long to debug just like that. try to remove elements until the crash no longer occurs.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate quesiton. hanks njzk2 for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with your ImageButtons... I don't think the XML inflater is happy with you using a weight and maxHeight at the same time... But it may be passing through because one of the attributes on your ImageButtons is for a higher API. Check the developer guide for all of them or remove them one by one until the crash disappears. It seems that all your ImageButtons are mostly identical, so I'd take that down to one for testing as well...

```
public int getDimensionPixelSize(int index, int defValue) {
    index *= AssetManager.STYLE_NUM_ENTRIES;
    final int[] data = mData;
    final int type = data[index+AssetManager.STYLE_TYPE];
    if (type == TypedValue.TYPE_NULL) {
        return defValue;
    } else if (type == TypedValue.TYPE_DIMENSION) {
        return TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(
            data[index+AssetManager.STYLE_DATA], mResources.mMetrics);
    }

    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Can't convert to dimension: type=0x" // Line 463 of TypedArray.java
            + Integer.toHexString(type));
}
```